# Can't remove Expo-cli

Tags: react-native, updates, expo

For some reasons I can't update or remove my version of Expo-cli.
I'm stuck on the 3.11.7 version. When I launch the update, it ends correctly but without being taken into account.

I've tested all the methods I've found but I haven't been able to uninstall it yet.
When I launch my project, it continues to launch normally with the v.3.11.7.

here are the commands line i already try :

```sh
yarn global remove expo-cli
npm -g uninstall expo-cli --save
sudo apt-get --purge remove expo-cli
yarn uninstall expo-cli
```

the expo --version commands is not working anymore ...

I need help please.

screenShot of the update request:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please confirm OS. Mine is Windows 10.

Look in appdata for yarn or npm install directories. You can find the globally installed package files and delete expo.

Essentially an npm or yarn version other than the one you're using has installed the expo-cli and now your current version can't find it.

I solved this by deleting the expo files in that dir

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Here's how I decided it ( Win 10 )

1. Open cmd as administrator and type `npm cache verify`
2. After that type `npm -g uninstall expo-cli --save`, if it freezing terminate it.
3. Remove from your user folder ".expo" folder.
4. Than try `npm -g uninstall expo-cli --save` in cmd, if it freezing terminate it and open some expo project.
5. type `yarn remove global expo-cli` and then `yarn add global expo-cli` in the project

Hope it helps somebody else too.